# Compare two sql tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables, one with text strings, and one with words.

[image]

How do I take each string/row in TABLE A and see how many of the "words" from TABLE B each string in TABLE A contains - and get a result like this:

TABLE A
id: 1 contains 2 words (car, red) from TABLE B
id: 2 contains 2 words (house, hill) from TABLE B
id: 3 contains 0 words from TABLE B
id: 4 contains 2 words (small, shoe) from TABLE B

Comment: Yes, and? What have you tried?

Comment: Probably textual sample data will be helpful

Comment: Joining tables, seperating tables, exporting arrays, and fiddleing around for hours...

Comment: This is going to be fun; Many answers are possible, but they will rarely be completely correct. (Do you have a sadistic teacher?)

Comment: This requires a double loop, with a function to split the string phrases into root words. which is not a simple MySQL query. I love the question though. Can be answered with a function of in conjunction with a display language (like PHP)

Comment: This isn't really what sql is good for

Comment: @JacquesAmar and Kiko, I join you with my opinion: the question is indeed very interesting.

Comment: @CitronAutobot Do you have to do it only in sql? If yes, then your only chance would be to use a stored procedure. Otherwise, PHP + sql. One question though: do you, personally, know, somehow, that it can work using only sql and without stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Get $TableA from TableA and $TableB from Table B (std code)

$result = array();
foreach ($TableA as $id => $string) {
    $result[$id] = array();
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (in_array($word, $TableB)) {
            $result[$id][] = $word;  
        }
    }
}

// - display $result - left as exercise!
```

Comment: And where do I call the sql tables?

Comment: I agree that using PHP makes this problem relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pure SQL solution using a `CROSS JOIN` in an aggregate query counting the `LIKE` instances between *string* and *word*. Below counts the total number with conditional `SUM` aggregation and outputs the words in comma-separated list with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.string LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.words, '%') 
                       THEN 1 
                       ELSE 0 
                  END) AS WordCount,
              GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.string LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.words, '%') 
                                THEN t2.words 
                                ELSE NULL 
                           END) AS Words
FROM Table1  t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.id
```

See [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/LMR87121).

WARNING: `CROSS JOIN` can deteriorate performance for large tables as a cartesian product (all possible combination pairings) is run between both sets which can run into millions very quickly.

Comment: LIKE isn't good approach for this because if string contains *fast and fastest* and word is *test* it will count it as 1 which is wrong

Comment: This might look like something in the right direction. However, how do I get from your example to a the result tables as shown in your rextester deme example?

Comment: Absolutely true @M Khalid Junaid ... OP should heed the warning. I may update with a different solution using full equality. @CitronAutobot ... I do not understand your question. This solution *is* in demo as last query. First two tables show reproduced data.

Comment: @Parfait - With my limited mySQL/php skills, I cannot manage to get the results you are getting. 
I am using PDO:

$conn = new PDO("mysql:$host$db_name,$username,$password"); 
$sql = " (YOUR CODE) ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($data = $q->fetch()){ 
??What to do here??
}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simply echo the *$data* array in `while` loop either by index, `$data[0]`, or column name, `$data['id']`.